# Missing word after \n command in Doxygen rtf output, version 1.8.5 & up

Tags: doxygen

It seems that if I use "\par Process:" followed by multiple lines of text with a \n command at the end of each line of text, the Doxygen rtf output will sometimes delete the first word at the beginning of the next line.

For example, if my original source looks like:

\par Process:

The quick brown fox jumped \n

over the lazy dog. \n

My output will look like:

Process:

The quick brown fox jumped the lazy dog.
(i.e., the first word after the \n, "over", is missing in the output.)

I've noticed that this problem occurs only in Doxygen versions 1.8.5 and later, and it only occurs in the rtf output (html looks fine).  I looked at the Doxygen version change logs and I'm wondering -- could it have anything to do with the "Avoid space in the output after \n command following by a newline" fix that was introduced in version 1.8.5?  Or am I using the \n command incorrectly?

Comment: Did you try to use <br> instead of \n? This looks like to work for me. Doing a difference on the refman.rtf of 1.8.4 and 1.85 gives (a.o.) that one of the \par commands is joined with the word over.

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed solution to github (pull request 165)

Comment: Hi @albert - I tried running 1.8.5 just now using <br> instead of \n in one section and it did seem to fix the missing words problem. Thanks for the suggestion!